# Asking Emacs-related questions at Super User, Stack Exchange, or Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have been reading an Emacs tutorial book and got questions when testing some Emacs features on my local machines. I wonder where to ask questions such as those two I have done at Stack Overflow:

- *[Run Emacs as a daemon and then the emacs binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54814420/run-emacs-as-a-daemon-and-then-the-emacs-binary)*
- *[Run Emacs as a daemon and then the emacs binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54814420/run-emacs-as-a-daemon-and-then-the-emacs-binary)*

Should I rather use Super User or Stack Exchange?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com

Comment: The two Stack Overflow links are identical.

Comment: Why did you link to the exact same question twice? Why did you link to the exact same question twice?

Answer (score 7):

The dedicated [Emacs Stack Exchange site](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/) will always be suitable, even though Emacs questions are generally also on-topic for Stack Overflow (as Emacs is a [software tool commonly used by programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)) and Super User (as long as it's [not about software development](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)).

Comment: This is the answer, IMO. But I often add a comment to a question when it is posted to two of those sites (typically SO and emacs.SE). I tell the OP that either is OK, but ask that s?he please choose just one and delete the other. The OP does so nearly always.